# createJs - 3d rotation around circle

Tags: html, canvas, createjs, easeljs, isometric

Now I really have a hard time. I have to make a rotating disc with objects on it, rotating around itself (3d illusion) on mousemove. It's really hard to get done. Any suggestions?

Comment: Somethimg like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z8aBZZnv6y8

Answer (score 0):

You can use path for the tween to move around.

Below are the sample code

```
 createjs.Tween.get(target).to({guide:{ path:[0,0, 0,200,200,200, 200,0,0,0] }},7000);
    // Visualizing the line
    graphics.moveTo(0,0).curveTo(0,200,200,200).curveTo(200,0,0,0)
```

Reffer
http://www.createjs.com/docs/tweenjs/classes/MotionGuidePlugin.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I made a fiddle using MotionGuidePlugin, but "graphics.moveTo" seems to be hard to understand how to work with.
https://jsfiddle.net/vNottbeck/a80oduu0/